# Filter Python String to utf8 character of bytes 3 or less

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, utf

I am trying to filter a python 3 string so that only utf8 characters of 3 bytes or less are kept (I am writing to a SQL db that is utf8_general_ci which can take only 3 bytes or less). Is there a straightforward way to do this in Python? Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), filter outside it.

```
''.join(c for c in S if c < '\U00010000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unicode code point equal and less then `0xffff` are encoded with 3 or less bytes (and above that, it requires 4 bytes).

so:

```
''.join(c for c in my_string if ord(c) <= 0xffff)
```

I'm not sure it Ignacio solution is faster: I have a function more (for every char) (`ord`), but `<` is just integer comparison. On the other solution, it should do a string comparison, which could be (but not sure) be complex.

What I do not like on Ignacio solution is the use of `<` on strings. Documentation say "*lexicographic*" sort, but such word (in English) on words has an other meaning. Sso in python '<' on strings is often a bug, but not in this case. I think it is one of the few bugs on Python design (`'B' < 'a'`, really?). The intention on my solution are (IMO) clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much Giamcomo . What are your thoughts on using:
''.join([_ for _ in my_string if len(_.encode('utf-8')) <=3])
might be slower though. Thoughts?

Comment: yes. the "encode" needs to check the size, in order to encode (+ various shift operators). Internal python representation is not UTF-8 [but if the full string it is ASCII]. Practically, internally, python has a sequence of codepoints, which are represented in 1, 2 or 4 bytes, according the larger codepoint. [so practically a UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, but just for the simple case, else it will pass to next encoding]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Giacomo Catenazzi. Answer is:
''.join(c for c in my_string if ord(c) <= 0xffff)

Alternative answer of 
''.join([_ for _ in my_string if len(_.encode('utf-8')) <=3])
runs at half the speed of ''.join(c for c in my_string if ord(c) <= 0xffff) .