# "Incorrect string value: '\\xD8\\xB9\\xD8\\xB1\\xD8\\xA8...' for column 'soup' at row 1". possible to filter 4 byte utf-8 chars?

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert scraped HTML data into a MySQL database using Python and SQLAlchemy.

I get this error over and over at various points in my scrape & save script:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD8\\xB9\\xD8\\xB1\\xD8\\xA8...' for column 'soup' at row 1")
```

Now, my research on this topic (thanks StackOverflow) tells me I cannot add 4 byte UTF-8 chars to my MySQL database *unless* I set the character encoding to `utf8mb4`.

Well, I did that. And it didn't work; I still get the error. See my sqlalchemy.create_engine statement here:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@localhost:3306/databaseName?charset=utf8mb4', echo=False)
```

I even went into MySQL, dropped the database & remade it. I still get the error message.

So does anyone know either (a) how I can filter out 4 byte UTF-8 chars from a string using Python3? or (b) how I can make my MySQL database accept 4 byte UTF-8 chars?

re: filtering 4 byte UTF-8 chars, I modified something I found on StackOverflow to read:

`filtered_x = ''.join(char for char in x if len(char.encode('utf-8')) < 3)` (via [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730466/remove-characters-with-encodings-larger-than-3-bytes-using-python-3))

but uh, it didn't work! As per the error msg, the problem is with "column soup". So I did this:

```
            filtered_soup = ''.join(char for char in the_page_soup if len(char.encode('utf-8', errors="ignore")) < 4)
            page_to_add = SqlPage(what=query_obj.query,
                                  where=query_obj.city,
                                  url=query_obj.soups[key].page_url,
                                  soup=filtered_soup)
```

But I'm still getting the error. What gives? (I did change `len(char.encode('utf-8', errors="ignore")) < 3` to `< 4` but I thought that makes sense... I'm trying to remove 4 byte chars, and `4 < 4 == false`, plus the error msg happens with `< 3` as well.)

Help please!

Edit: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013072/filter-python-string-to-utf8-character-of-bytes-3-or-less) has some nice responses re: filtering, but they look the same as my solution... and after trying them, they don't work.

Here's the full error msg in case I am missing something...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database/database.py", line 272, in <module>
    query_status = add_plain_query_to_database(Query(lang, city))
  File "database/database.py", line 134, in add_plain_query_to_database
    session.commit()  # should add all the pages and posts to the database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 503, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 482, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2479, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2617, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2577, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1137, in _emit_insert_statements
    statement, params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xD8\\xB9\\xD8\\xB1\\xD8\\xA8...' for column 'soup' at row 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO page (parent_id, url, soup, what, `where`, num_of_posts) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)]
[parameters: (3L, 'https://www.indeed.ca/jobs?q=vue&l=Vancouver%2C+BC&start=20&limit=20', u'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html dir="ltr" lang="en">\n <head>\n  <meta content="text/html;charset=ignore" http-equiv="content-type"/>\n  <script src="/s/812e ... (649747 characters truncated) ... img = new Image(); img.src = href;}}; window[\'sendPageLoadEndPing\']("serp", "1e2p9l9jm5196800", "1583544444534");\n  </script>\n </body>\n</html>\n', 'vue', 'Vancouver', None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: You have to actually alter the table to use the `utf8b4` encoding. Ideally you alter _all_ the tables, plus the database encoding, and make sure all your defaults match as well.

Comment: Something like ```table_row = Column(Unicode(2, collation='utf8b4')```? or ```charset="utf8b4"``` in the create_engine string?

Comment: (The above 2 comments are missing `m` in `utf8mb4`.)

Comment: @RolyPoly - `utf8mb4` is a _character set_, not a _collation_.

Comment: Oh, it's missing a letter. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your were hoping to get 'عرب'?

But some layer was changing each Arabic character into something like `\\xD8\\xB9`.  That's 4 hex digits `D8B9`, which is *one* UTF-8 character for the Arabic letter 'AIN'.

Arabic characters are 2-byte encodings in UTF-8.  So, `utf8mb4` is not 'required' here.  My point is, that `utf8mb4` vs `utf8` is not the issue.

I suspect the doubling up of the backslashes is the problem.  Does the text come from client code?  Via what statement?  Can you dump the string in hex from the client code?

Check the Python tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Maybe something in these sqlalchemy notes:

```
db_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(drivername='mysql', host=foo.db_host,
    database=db_schema,
    query={ 'read_default_file' : foo.db_config, 'charset': 'utf8mb4' })
```

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost/testdb?charset=utf8', encoding = 'utf-8')

Or here:  https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-unicode

You should probably remove `len(char.encode...`

Comment: >"Does the text come from client code?" Nope, it's all my own hobby program. re: "Can you dump the string in hex" I would do it if the string was < 500 char long, but it's gonna be the HTML from a webpage, approx 550,000 chars. I might be able to isolate the chars causing the error somehow...

Comment: @RolyPoly - How did the string get into your program?  Did you type it?  Did you fetch it somehow from somewhere?  I suspect Python can extract a substring and display it in HEX; I don't know about sqlalchemy.

Comment: I will look through my code for places that could be causing the doubling up of the backslashes. "How did the string get into your program?" I did ```page_html = requests.get(url)``` and parsed the string using BeautifulSoup like so: ```string = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")```. So what I'll do is do something like ```if string[index:index+4] == "\\xD8\\xB9", print(string[index:index+50])```. one sec

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting the substring with ```\\xD8\\xB9...```. ```soup_to_add = query_obj.soups[key].soup.decode("utf-8", "ignore")

            misfit_index = soup_to_add.find("xD8")
            print("PRINTING")
            print(misfit_index)
            print(soup_to_add[misfit_index:misfit_index+500])``` prints nothing except "printing".

Comment: Here is the offending string: ```عربي"},BE:{en:"En",nl:"Nl",fr:"Fr",de:"De"},BH:{en:"En",ar:"عربي"},CH:{en:"En",de:"De",fr:"Fr",it:"It"},EG:{en:"En",ar:"عربي"},FI:{fi:"Fi",sv:"Sv"},HK:{en:"En",zh:"中文"},ID:{en:"En",in:"Id"},IL:{en:"En",il:"עִברִית"},KW:{en:"En",ar:"عربي"},LU:{en:"En",de:"De",fr:"Fr"},MA:{en:"En",ar:"عربي",fr:"Fr"},OM:{en:"En",ar:"عربي"},QA:{en:"En",ar:"عربي"},SA:{en:"En",ar:"عربي"},SG:{en:"En",zh:"中0文```

Comment: I think I got it. I found a function "is_english" and used that. Thanks for your help Rick